# how to get the time difference between two datetime rows that are in 12 hour system

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to get the time difference in a dataframe that has date and time on separate columns. I started by combining the date and time columns first and I have been able to get the difference but since the time is in 12 hour system, I keep getting negative values.
I am not very proficient in R and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I am adding the code I used with a sample of what my data looks like.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

sampledata<-"Date       Time    
10/1/2001   4.00
10/1/2001   4.15
10/1/2001   4.30
10/1/2001   4.45
10/1/2001   5.00
10/1/2001   5.15
10/1/2001   5.30
10/1/2001   5.45
10/1/2001   6.00
10/1/2001   6.15
10/1/2001   6.30
10/2/2001   6.45
10/2/2001   7.00
10/2/2001   7.15
10/2/2001   7.30
10/2/2001   7.45
10/2/2001   8.00
10/2/2001   8.15
10/2/2001   8.30
10/2/2001   8.45
10/2/2001   9.00
10/2/2001   9.15
10/2/2001   9.30
10/2/2001   9.45
10/2/2001   10.00
10/2/2001   10.15
10/2/2001   10.30
10/2/2001   10.45
10/2/2001   11.00
10/2/2001   11.15
10/2/2001   11.30
10/2/2001   11.45
10/2/2001   12.00
10/2/2001   12.15
10/2/2001   12.30
10/2/2001   12.45
10/2/2001   1.00
10/2/2001   1.15
10/2/2001   1.30
10/2/2001   1.45
10/2/2001   2.00
10/2/2001   2.15
10/2/2001   2.30
10/2/2001   2.45
10/2/2001   3.00
10/2/2001   3.15
10/2/2001   3.30
10/2/2001   4.00
10/2/2001   4.15
10/2/2001   4.30
10/2/2001   4.45
10/2/2001   5.00
10/2/2001   5.15
10/2/2001   5.30
10/2/2001   5.45
10/2/2001   6.00
10/3/2001   6.15
10/3/2001   6.30
10/3/2001   6.45
10/3/2001   7.00
10/3/2001   7.15
10/3/2001   7.30
10/3/2001   7.45
10/3/2001   8.00
10/3/2001   8.15
10/3/2001   8.30
10/3/2001   8.45
10/3/2001   9.00
10/3/2001   9.15
10/3/2001   9.30
10/3/2001   9.45
10/3/2001   10.00
10/3/2001   10.15
10/3/2001   10.30
10/3/2001   10.45
10/3/2001   11.00
10/3/2001   11.15
10/3/2001   11.30
10/3/2001   11.45
10/3/2001   12.00
10/3/2001   12.15
10/3/2001   12.30
10/3/2001   12.45
10/3/2001   1.00
10/3/2001   1.15
10/3/2001   1.30
10/3/2001   1.45
10/3/2001   2.00
10/3/2001   2.15
10/3/2001   2.30
10/3/2001   2.45
10/3/2001   3.00
10/3/2001   3.15
10/3/2001   3.30
10/3/2001   3.45
10/3/2001   4.00
10/3/2001   4.15
10/3/2001   4.30
10/3/2001   4.45
10/3/2001   5.00
10/3/2001   5.15
10/3/2001   5.30
10/3/2001   5.45
10/3/2001   6.00"

#read data
usedata <- read.table(text=sampledata, header = TRUE)

#Combining Date and Time columns
usedata$datetime<-with(usedata, mdy(usedata$Date) + hm(usedata$Time))

#Converting datetime to date and time variables
usedata$datetime<-as.POSIXct(usedata$datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")

#Calculating time difference between each time interval 
df<-usedata %>%
  group_by(Date)%>%
  mutate(Time_Duration = (difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = datetime[1]), unit='secs'))) 
df

df$Time_Duration
```

When the time changes from 12 pm to 1 pm, the time difference given by df$Time_Duration is negative. I am assuming this is an issue with the fact that my time is in the 12 hour system but maybe it is something else.
I tried using strptime and format to convert the datetime column to 24 hour first before finding the difference but I get NA values for the datetime column.

I tried the following strptime code to convert to 24 hours

```
x <- strptime(usedata$datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
x

format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Any help I can get will be super appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Are your dates and times all in strictly increasing order as in you example?

Comment: If your data does not include AM/PM (or similar), how do you "know" what each time really represents?

Comment: Yes, it's a really long dataset starting from 2001 to  2010, with the dates increasing

Comment: r2evans, the time column was entered without specifying the am/pm but for each date I know that the time starts from AM and then ends with PM, in my example for 10/1/2001, the time starts at 4 am and ends at 945 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this ought to do it. The key points were to convert the decimal numbers in the time column to strings with a fixed number of decimal places, pasting the date and time columns together, and using the correct `format` in `strptime`. If the difference between consecutive times is negative within a particular date, you know you can add 12 hours to it and all following times on that day.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

sampledata %>% 
  mutate(Datetime = as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(Date, format(Time, nsmall = 2)), 
                             format = "%m/%d/%Y %H.%M"))) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(diff_t = cumsum(as.numeric(c(0, as.numeric(diff(Datetime))) < 0))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Datetime =  as.POSIXct(ifelse(diff_t == 1, Datetime + hours(12), Datetime),
                     origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  select(-diff_t) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Yielding the following result:

```
#>          Date  Time            Datetime
#> 1   10/1/2001  4.00 2001-10-01 04:00:00
#> 2   10/1/2001  4.15 2001-10-01 04:15:00
#> 3   10/1/2001  4.30 2001-10-01 04:30:00
#> 4   10/1/2001  4.45 2001-10-01 04:45:00
#> 5   10/1/2001  5.00 2001-10-01 05:00:00
#> 6   10/1/2001  5.15 2001-10-01 05:15:00
#> 7   10/1/2001  5.30 2001-10-01 05:30:00
#> 8   10/1/2001  5.45 2001-10-01 05:45:00
#> 9   10/1/2001  6.00 2001-10-01 06:00:00
#> 10  10/1/2001  6.15 2001-10-01 06:15:00
#> 11  10/1/2001  6.30 2001-10-01 06:30:00
#> 12  10/2/2001  6.45 2001-10-02 06:45:00
#> 13  10/2/2001  7.00 2001-10-02 07:00:00
#> 14  10/2/2001  7.15 2001-10-02 07:15:00
#> 15  10/2/2001  7.30 2001-10-02 07:30:00
#> 16  10/2/2001  7.45 2001-10-02 07:45:00
#> 17  10/2/2001  8.00 2001-10-02 08:00:00
#> 18  10/2/2001  8.15 2001-10-02 08:15:00
#> 19  10/2/2001  8.30 2001-10-02 08:30:00
#> 20  10/2/2001  8.45 2001-10-02 08:45:00
#> 21  10/2/2001  9.00 2001-10-02 09:00:00
#> 22  10/2/2001  9.15 2001-10-02 09:15:00
#> 23  10/2/2001  9.30 2001-10-02 09:30:00
#> 24  10/2/2001  9.45 2001-10-02 09:45:00
#> 25  10/2/2001 10.00 2001-10-02 10:00:00
#> 26  10/2/2001 10.15 2001-10-02 10:15:00
#> 27  10/2/2001 10.30 2001-10-02 10:30:00
#> 28  10/2/2001 10.45 2001-10-02 10:45:00
#> 29  10/2/2001 11.00 2001-10-02 11:00:00
#> 30  10/2/2001 11.15 2001-10-02 11:15:00
#> 31  10/2/2001 11.30 2001-10-02 11:30:00
#> 32  10/2/2001 11.45 2001-10-02 11:45:00
#> 33  10/2/2001 12.00 2001-10-02 12:00:00
#> 34  10/2/2001 12.15 2001-10-02 12:15:00
#> 35  10/2/2001 12.30 2001-10-02 12:30:00
#> 36  10/2/2001 12.45 2001-10-02 12:45:00
#> 37  10/2/2001  1.00 2001-10-02 13:00:00
#> 38  10/2/2001  1.15 2001-10-02 13:15:00
#> 39  10/2/2001  1.30 2001-10-02 13:30:00
#> 40  10/2/2001  1.45 2001-10-02 13:45:00
#> 41  10/2/2001  2.00 2001-10-02 14:00:00
#> 42  10/2/2001  2.15 2001-10-02 14:15:00
#> 43  10/2/2001  2.30 2001-10-02 14:30:00
#> 44  10/2/2001  2.45 2001-10-02 14:45:00
#> 45  10/2/2001  3.00 2001-10-02 15:00:00
#> 46  10/2/2001  3.15 2001-10-02 15:15:00
#> 47  10/2/2001  3.30 2001-10-02 15:30:00
#> 48  10/2/2001  4.00 2001-10-02 16:00:00
#> 49  10/2/2001  4.15 2001-10-02 16:15:00
#> 50  10/2/2001  4.30 2001-10-02 16:30:00
#> 51  10/2/2001  4.45 2001-10-02 16:45:00
#> 52  10/2/2001  5.00 2001-10-02 17:00:00
#> 53  10/2/2001  5.15 2001-10-02 17:15:00
#> 54  10/2/2001  5.30 2001-10-02 17:30:00
#> 55  10/2/2001  5.45 2001-10-02 17:45:00
#> 56  10/2/2001  6.00 2001-10-02 18:00:00
#> 57  10/3/2001  6.15 2001-10-03 06:15:00
#> 58  10/3/2001  6.30 2001-10-03 06:30:00
#> 59  10/3/2001  6.45 2001-10-03 06:45:00
#> 60  10/3/2001  7.00 2001-10-03 07:00:00
#> 61  10/3/2001  7.15 2001-10-03 07:15:00
#> 62  10/3/2001  7.30 2001-10-03 07:30:00
#> 63  10/3/2001  7.45 2001-10-03 07:45:00
#> 64  10/3/2001  8.00 2001-10-03 08:00:00
#> 65  10/3/2001  8.15 2001-10-03 08:15:00
#> 66  10/3/2001  8.30 2001-10-03 08:30:00
#> 67  10/3/2001  8.45 2001-10-03 08:45:00
#> 68  10/3/2001  9.00 2001-10-03 09:00:00
#> 69  10/3/2001  9.15 2001-10-03 09:15:00
#> 70  10/3/2001  9.30 2001-10-03 09:30:00
#> 71  10/3/2001  9.45 2001-10-03 09:45:00
#> 72  10/3/2001 10.00 2001-10-03 10:00:00
#> 73  10/3/2001 10.15 2001-10-03 10:15:00
#> 74  10/3/2001 10.30 2001-10-03 10:30:00
#> 75  10/3/2001 10.45 2001-10-03 10:45:00
#> 76  10/3/2001 11.00 2001-10-03 11:00:00
#> 77  10/3/2001 11.15 2001-10-03 11:15:00
#> 78  10/3/2001 11.30 2001-10-03 11:30:00
#> 79  10/3/2001 11.45 2001-10-03 11:45:00
#> 80  10/3/2001 12.00 2001-10-03 12:00:00
#> 81  10/3/2001 12.15 2001-10-03 12:15:00
#> 82  10/3/2001 12.30 2001-10-03 12:30:00
#> 83  10/3/2001 12.45 2001-10-03 12:45:00
#> 84  10/3/2001  1.00 2001-10-03 13:00:00
#> 85  10/3/2001  1.15 2001-10-03 13:15:00
#> 86  10/3/2001  1.30 2001-10-03 13:30:00
#> 87  10/3/2001  1.45 2001-10-03 13:45:00
#> 88  10/3/2001  2.00 2001-10-03 14:00:00
#> 89  10/3/2001  2.15 2001-10-03 14:15:00
#> 90  10/3/2001  2.30 2001-10-03 14:30:00
#> 91  10/3/2001  2.45 2001-10-03 14:45:00
#> 92  10/3/2001  3.00 2001-10-03 15:00:00
#> 93  10/3/2001  3.15 2001-10-03 15:15:00
#> 94  10/3/2001  3.30 2001-10-03 15:30:00
#> 95  10/3/2001  3.45 2001-10-03 15:45:00
#> 96  10/3/2001  4.00 2001-10-03 16:00:00
#> 97  10/3/2001  4.15 2001-10-03 16:15:00
#> 98  10/3/2001  4.30 2001-10-03 16:30:00
#> 99  10/3/2001  4.45 2001-10-03 16:45:00
#> 100 10/3/2001  5.00 2001-10-03 17:00:00
#> 101 10/3/2001  5.15 2001-10-03 17:15:00
#> 102 10/3/2001  5.30 2001-10-03 17:30:00
#> 103 10/3/2001  5.45 2001-10-03 17:45:00
#> 104 10/3/2001  6.00 2001-10-03 18:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. I just added  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(Time_Duration = (difftime(Datetime, lag(Datetime, default = Datetime[1]), unit='secs'))) to get the difference and now I don't have negative values. thank you